# Convert Perl regular expressions to SQL regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, perl, firebird

I need to use Perl regular expressions in a Firebird database.

Firebird RDBMS does support regular expressions by providing a [`SIMILAR TO`-condition](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-similar-to.html).
Unfortunately, the SQL regular expression syntax in Firebird differs from Perl syntax.

**Is it possible to convert Perl regular expressions to SQL regular expressions?**
I do not need full compatibility but at least quantifiers and character classes should be convertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the following replacement rules (the order matters) to convert most Perl regular expressions to SQL syntax:

At first, SQL special characters have to be escaped:

1. `_` > `\_`
2. `%` > `\%`

Then, Perl special characters and character classes have to be replaced.

3. `.` > `_`
4. `\d`> `[:digit:]`
5. `\D` > `[^[:digit:]]`
6. `\w` > `[^[:whitespace:]]`
7. `\W` > `[:whitespace:]`
8. `\s` > `[:whitespace:]`
9. `\S` > `[^[:whitespace:]]`

Note: The default Perl escape character `\` is used for `SIMILAR TO` here.

Feel free, to extend my answer with further possible replacements.

Answer (score 2):

> [I] do not need full compatibility but at least quantifiers and character classes should be convertible.

You are lucky, you may use character classes, `?`, `*`, `+`, `{exact_occurrences_number}`, `{min,}`, `{min,max}` quantifiers with [Firebird `SIMILAR TO` regex syntax](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-similar-to.html).

The only trouble are Unicode category/property classes, you may only use POSIX character classes there:

> `<predefined class name>  ::=  ALPHA | UPPER | LOWER | DIGIT`
>                                                       `| ALNUM | SPACE | WHITESPACE`